# Deriving heat capacity in terms of internal energy U and natural variables S & V

Tags: thermodynamics

My lecture notes have the following equation regarding heat capacities:

$$
C_p = C_v + T\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_v\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p
$$

(just to be clear, all terms after the brackets in this question indicate a constant process of that term)

It then states that by using internal energy $U$, volume $V$ and entropy $S$, you can express heat capacity at constant pressure, $C_p$, just in terms of these 3 variables:

$$
C_p = \frac {\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_v\left(\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial V^2}\right)_s }{\left(\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial V^2}\right)_s\left(\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial S^2}\right)_v - \left(\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial S \cdot\partial V}\right)^2}
$$

with no inbetween steps given.

From a previous derivation of $C_v$ I know that:

$$
C_v = \frac{\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_v}{\left(\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial S^2}\right)_v}
$$

and I think I understand at the least how to express the $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_v$ term, because you can express $p$ and $T$ in terms of $U, S, V$ like so:

$$
\begin{align*}
-p &= \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_s \\
T &= \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_v
\end{align*}
$$

The real killer is the second term $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$, because the only thing I know I can do with this equation is use the Maxwell relation:

$$
-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_T
$$

but this still leaves a constant temperature term $T$ which is not present in the final equation. So, any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Suggested reading: Physical Chemistry, Peter Atkins and Julio de Paula.

Comment: Read this [Ref.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) and [Ref.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities)

Comment: In the first equation you quoted, the natural variables are either $T$ and $P$ or $T$ and $V$. On the other hand, in the equation you are trying to derive, the natural variables are $S$ and $V$. It should in principle be possible to start from the former and arrive at the latter through a series of manipulations, but it should be much easier to simply start from scratch with the natural variables $S$ and $V$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually this part of thermodynamics is not presented in the most efficient way. To derive the expression for, e.g., $C_P - C_V$, one goes through a series of steps involving Maxwell's relations and the [triple product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule). Figuring out what to do in each step is done mostly by guesswork.

However, all relations of these sorts really come from just a single mathematical relation that more generally holds. That is to say,

> Consider a twice-differentiable,  two-variable function $f(x,y)$ and its Legendre transform with respect to $y$, defined by $g(x,f_y) := f - f_y y$. <sup>1</sup>  Here, $f_y$ denotes the derivative of $f$ with respect of $y$ with other independent variables held fixed. Then, the following identity is satisfied:
>   \begin{equation}
> \boxed{g_{xx}  - f_{xx}  = - \frac{f_{xy}^2}{f_{yy}} = \frac{g_{x f_y}^2}{g_{f_y f_y}}}.
> \end{equation}
>   **Proof**. We have 
>   \begin{equation}
> \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigg)_{f_y} = f_x + f_y \bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)_{f_y} = f_x - f_y \frac{f_{xy}}{f_{yy}}.
> \end{equation}
>   On the above, the first equality holds because of the chain rule [for the change of variables $(x,y)$ $\to$ $(x, f_y)$], and the second equality because of the triple product rule. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> g_x = \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigg)_{f_y} - f_y\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)_{f_y}   =f_x,
> \end{equation}
>   and
>   \begin{equation}
> g_{xx} = \bigg(\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x} \bigg)_{f_y}= f_{xx} + f_{xy}\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)_{f_y} = f_{xx} - \frac{f_{xy}^2}{f_{yy}}.
> \end{equation}
>   Also, using the chain rule for the change of variables $(x,y)$ $\to$ $(x, f_y)$, we get
>   \begin{equation}
> g_{f_y} = \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial f_y} \bigg)_{x} -\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial f_y} \bigg)_{x}f_y - y = -y.
> \end{equation}
>   Therefore, Legendre transform of $g$ with respect to $f_y$ is simply $g - g_{f_y} f_y = f$. Then, performing a similar analysis as above for $g$ gives
>   \begin{equation}
> f_{xx} = g_{xx} - \frac{g_{x f_y}^2}{g_{f_y f_y}}.
> \end{equation}

Now, all that remains to be done is to choose the variables and functions $x$, $y$, $f$ and $g$. Below are some examples.

(1) $x = S$, $y = V$, $f = U$, $g = H$, and $f_y = -P$:
\begin{equation}
H_{SS} - U_{SS} = -\frac{U_{SV}^2}{U_{VV}}.
\end{equation}
Note that
\begin{equation}
U_{SS} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S^2}\bigg)_V = \bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\bigg)_V = \frac{T}{T(\partial S/\partial T)_V} = \frac{T}{C_V},
\end{equation}
and that, similarly,
\begin{equation}
H_{SS} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial S^2}\bigg)_P = \bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\bigg)_P = \frac{T}{T(\partial S/\partial T)_P} = \frac{T}{C_P}.
\end{equation}
Hence, we have
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{1}{C_P} - \frac{1}{C_V} = -\frac{U_{SV}^2}{T U_{VV}} = -\frac{\Big(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S \partial V}\Big)^2}{\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\Big)_V \Big(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial V^2}\Big)_S}}
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to the relation OP wanted to derive.

(2) $x = T$, $y = V$, $f = A$, $g = G$, $f_y = -P$, and noting that $f_{-y} = -f_y$,
\begin{equation}
G_{TT} - A_{TT} = \frac{G_{T,-P}^2}{G_{-P,-P}} = \frac{G_{TP}^2}{G_{PP}}.
\end{equation}
Here,
\begin{equation}
A_{TT} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial T^2}\bigg)_V = -\bigg(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\bigg)_V = - \frac{1}{T}C_V,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
G_{TT} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T^2}\bigg)_P = -\bigg(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\bigg)_P = - \frac{1}{T}C_P,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
G_{TP} = \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T \partial P} = \bigg(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\bigg)_P = V \alpha,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha := \frac{1}{V}\Big(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\Big)_P$ is the volume expansion coefficient,
\begin{equation}
G_{PP} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P^2}\bigg)_T = \bigg(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\bigg)_T = - V\kappa_T,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa_T := -\frac{1}{V}\Big(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\Big)_T$ is the isothermal compressibility. Then, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\boxed{C_p - C_V = \frac{TV\alpha^2}{\kappa_T}}.
\end{equation}

(3) $x = V$, $y = S$, $f = H$, $g = G$, and $f_y = T$:
\begin{equation}
G_{PP} - H_{PP} = \frac{G_{TP}^2}{G_{TT}}.
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
H_{PP} = \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial P^2}\bigg)_S = \bigg(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\bigg)_S = - V\kappa_S,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa_S := -\frac{1}{V}\Big(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\Big)_S$ is the adiabatic compressibility. We have already shown that
\begin{equation}
G_{PP} = -V\kappa_T, \quad G_{TP} = V \alpha, \quad G_{TT} = - \frac{C_P}{T},
\end{equation}
whence we obtain
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\kappa_T - \kappa_S = \frac{TV\alpha^2}{C_P}}.
\end{equation}

---

<sup>1</sup> To be more precise, one should first write down $f(x,y) - y f_y$ and then express $y$ as a function of $x$ and $f_y$. Also, for the Legendre transform to exist, $f(x,y)$ should be a convex or concave function of $y$.